# Infer 64 bit key from 48-bit round key in DES

Tags: cryptography, des

I have the 48-bit round key for the last round in DES. I would like to recover the 64-bit master key from it.

Is it possible? If yes, can anyone provide the algorithm to do so.

Comment: If you have a 48-bit round key then you have 48 bits of the 56 bit (not 64) DES key. To recover the remaining unknown 8 bits of the key you'll need some data encrypted with the key. Try all 256 remaining possibilities and the one possibility that correctly decrypts the ciphertext is the answer.

Comment: The remaining bit from each of eight octets providing 56 bits of key is used for odd parity.